# Formula to calculate the difference between two date/time fields in hours:minute format (values in 12-hour clock format)

Tags: formula

What is a formula to calculate the difference between two date/time fields in hours:minute (both date/time values in 12-hour clock format)?

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck? This [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&language=en_US) may help

Comment: suppose Date1: 2/4/2015 8:47 PM and DateTime2: 2/6/2015 2:37 AM I want difference between these dates in hours and minute. can you please help me to create formula field

Answer (score 5):

The [examples](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_examples_dates.htm&language=en_US) which are mentioned in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&language=en_US) contains the following:

> **Finding the Elapsed Time Between Date/Times**
>
> To find the difference between two Date values, subtract one from the
>   other like so: **date_1 — date_2** to return the difference in days.
>
> Finding the elapsed time between two Date/Time values is slightly more
>   complex. For simplicity, the custom field **Diff_c** refers to the
>   difference between two Date/Time values. Since **Diff_c** is a number,
>   you can use this formula to convert it to days, hours, and minutes.
>
> ```
> IF(
>   Diff_c > 0 ,
>   TEXT( FLOOR( Diff_c ) ) & " days "
>   & TEXT( FLOOR( MOD( Diff_c * 24, 24 ) ) ) & " hours "
>   & TEXT( ROUND( MOD( Diff_c * 24 * 60, 60 ), 0 ) ) & " minutes",
>   ""
> )
> ```